# difference between len and sizeof

Tags: python, data-structures, struct, sizeof

I am using python 3.6 - and I am trying to use the struct library to pack little endian data packets to be sent to a custom protocol using UDP.

If we do `len(struct.pack('<hhislddiii',1,2,3,b'C',1,2,3,4,5,6))` then we get 41 which is the correct length in terms of bytes. However, if we do `struct.pack('<hhislddiii',1,2,3,b'C',1,2,3,4,5,6).__sizeof__()` we get 58. Can someone please explain what is the difference between these two ? I am trying to craft a packet using scapy as a UDP packet, hence getting the right packet format is crucial. Wanted to understand the difference.

Comment: `sizeof` is the size of Python's internal data structure. It includes information such as the type of the object and the reference count. It bears only a limited relation to the number of bytes in the data you are setting up, and will often be bigger; and sometimes smaller, for example, a list, which stores references to the elements of the list, not the data. `sizeof` is primarily useful when you have huge data structures and are running out of memory.

Comment: Thank you ! Yes I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

`len` is the number of items in a collection. `__sizeof__` is the size of that object in bytes. Also, you usually wouldn't call `__sizeof__` on its own, the Pythonic thing to do is to call `sys.getsizeof(object_name)`.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)

Comment: In this case there are not 41 elements so not sure I understand your answer. There are 41 bytes by intention. Noted about the pythonic thing - but do you perhaps know what are the additional 17 bytes used for ?

Comment: Fair enough, I can't explain this exact case.